# 1 server 2 Tomcat 1 docbase 1 logfile - can this setup cause logs missing?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

Background

- 1 server
- running 2 tomcat8
- using 1 same docbase for both tomcat
- using 1 same log4j2.properties for both tomcat

I found out some of transaction logs are missing randomly, is it bad practice writing a single log file from two different application using same source?

For example, if there were 60,000 API calls, then maybe about 5 calls or more logs are missing.

I can tell "there's a missing transaction" because I can find API request/reponse from DB but no log for that transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was thinking more about this setup,
this would be a bad idea because

- Two applications write to a single log file, would corrupt the file with log4j (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23998294/1042903)
- Even if this would not be a problem, there's still an issue with rolling file, which two different applications would compete rolling a single log file.

Eventually, I have to separate document base and write separate log files and then use LogStash or some other logging framework to view them at one place.

Ref: Someone is asking for Prudent mode of Logback for Log4j2 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1828)

Afterwards,

1. I changed catalina.sh script to add jvm option which would include different directory or log file name for each tomcat
2. also change log4j2.properties to access jvm argument using ${sys:option_name}
3. restart each tomcat to see if option is set correctly

Ref: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#JmxRuntimeInputArgumentsLookup